# MySQL: unique rows with minimal date

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

Imagine I have following table:

```
NAME DATE OTHER_CONTANT

'A' '2012-06-05' 'baz'
'A' '2012-06-04' 'bar'
'B' '2012-06-05' 'foo'
'C' '2012-06-05' 'bla'
'C' '2012-06-04' 'blah'
'C' '2012-06-06' 'bleh'
```

Now I want to filter this table to contain only rows with unique NAME and earliest date:

```
'A' '2012-06-04' 'bar'
'B' '2012-06-05' 'foo'
'C' '2012-06-04' 'blah'
```

I was thinking about using GROUP BY statement but with GROUP BY I can get only one column as result and i want to get whole rows. Any suggestions of how to make this filtering?

Comment: @mnowotka : Do you want `OTHER_CONTANT ` too in your output??

Comment: Yes, exactly and perhabs there are even more columns and I want to avoid enumarating their names in my query.

Comment: @mnowotka : Then check others answers. The fiddle provided by beny23 is working..

Comment: I'm going to evaluate all of them and accept the valid one with shortest execution time. Nice discussion by the way.

Comment: Can a particular name have the same date more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both query works perfectly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   MyTable a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT name, 
                          Min(date) AS date 
                   FROM   MyTable 
                   GROUP  BY name) b 
               ON a.name = b.name 
                  AND a.date = b.date
```

or

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   mytable a 
       LEFT JOIN mytable b 
              ON a.name = b.name
                 AND a.date > b.date 
WHERE  b.name IS NULL
```

Comment: The first one seems to be much faster.

Comment: It may depend on defined indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following:

```
select m.name, m.date, m.other_constant 
  from mytable m
  join (select name, min(date) min_date from mytable group by name) n
    on m.name = n.name and m.date = n.min_date
```

See also the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcb1d/3/0) for this.

Comment: +1 for the SQL Fiddle, always nice to actually test your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL creates a list of all distinct names.  Then for each name, it looks for the entry with the latest date.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  distinct name
        from    YourTable
        ) names
join    YourTable yt1
on      yt1.name = names.name
        and yt1.date =
        (
        select  date
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.name = yt1.name
        order by
                date
        limit   1
        )
```

[Live example using beny23's SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3396/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
   select name, min(date) as mindate, other_contact
   from table_name group by name
   ) as x
   inner join table_name as f 
   on f.name = x.name and f.date= x.mindate;
```

Comment: I don't like enumarating all column names in the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    a.date,
    b.other_contant
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            name,
            MIN(date) AS date,
        FROM
            yourtable
        GROUP BY 
            name
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    yourtable b ON a.name = b.name AND a.date = b.date
```

Comment: I don't like enumarating all column names in the inner query.